# Outlook VBA move sent mail based on SendAs address

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I am trying to move sent mail from my regular Sent Items standard folder to two separate folders in Outlook (365). On the left in my Folder Pane I have my email 'main@domain.com', 'Online Archive - main@domain.com' (an Online Archive for more storage similar to a PST I guess) and then a shared mailbox 'secondary@domain.com'.

One of the backup folders is in my Online Archive and the other backup folder is a shared mailbox. Here's the VBA code I have so far. Ideally I would like it to run each time an email is sent/appears in the Sent Items so I think I could use WithEvents somehow but I am okay to run the macro on an as needed basis.

When I run the code none of the mail moves so I think the issue is something with how I am selecting the filtered mail items to move.

```
Sub MoveItems()

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim mySource As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object

Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set mySource = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set myItems = mySource.Items

    Set myDestFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders("Online Archive - main@domain.com").Folders("Backup")
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'main@domain.com'")
    
        While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
        Wend
       
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'secondary@domain.com'")
    Set myDestFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders("secondary@domain.com").Folders("SecondaryBackup")
        
        While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
        Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: See [Apply one of two results to incoming email with Item_Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453348/apply-one-of-two-results-to-incoming-email-with-item-add)

Comment: @niton I'm trying to do this to sent emails and not received ones. I'll see if I can use part of that on Monday.

Comment: Replace `Set myItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).items` with a reference to the sent mail folder. `Set myItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).items`

Comment: I already referenced `olFolderSentMail in the existing code that failed to run and the link there is about saving attachments not moving mail between folders.

Comment: New conversation: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code. Edit the question post to indicate the problem.

Comment: Verify SenderEmailAddress is in SMTP not Exchange format. `Debug.Print ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).senderEmailAddress`

Comment: @niton yeah that's the issue. Debut.Print outputs the below where ??? is a random unique values specific to my outlook I assume

`/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (???)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=???

Comment: @niton I updated the original post with the solution I discovered. Thanks again for the guidance.

Comment: Good that you found a solution and posted an answer. I rolled your edit back so this post remains the question part of the Q & A.

Comment: Exchange address: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945487/ms-outlook-2010-senderemailaddress-returns-a-huge-string-of-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MoveItems()

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim mySource, myDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object
Dim strFilter As String

Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set mySource = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set myItems = mySource.Items

strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & Chr(34) & " like '%Main Display Name%'"

    Set myDestFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders("Online Archive - main@domain.com").Folders("Backup")
    Set myItem = myItems.Find(strFilter)
    
        While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
        Wend
        
strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & Chr(34) & " like '%Shared Box Display Name%'"

    Set myDestFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders("Shared Box Display Name").Folders("Backup")
    Set myItem = myItems.Find(strFilter)
    
        While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
        Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change to `senderName` if `senderEmailAddress` is not in SMTP format.

```vb
Sub MoveItems_senderName()

    Dim mySource As Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Folder
    Dim myItems As Items
    Dim myItem As Object
    
    Set mySource = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    'mySource.Display
    
    Set myItems = mySource.Items

    Set myDestFolder = Session.Folders("Online Archive - main@domain.com").Folders("Backup")
    
    Debug.Print "senderName: " & senderName
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'text from immediate pane'")
    
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend

End Sub
```