# Apply ItemChange event to all subfolders of my inbox

Tags: vba, outlook, categories

I created subfolders in my inbox with rules that mails from a person automatically get moved to their folder.

In these folders I work with categories. After assigning a green category I want the mail to move to the green category folder I made.

This code checks my main inbox folder. How can I check all subfolders as well? Note this is not my own code.

```vb
Private WithEvents xInboxFld As Outlook.Folder
Private WithEvents xInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    MsgBox "Macros are working"

    Set xInboxFld = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set xInboxItems = xInboxFld.Items
End Sub


Private Sub xInboxItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

MsgBox "Item Changed"

Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xFlds As Outlook.Folders
Dim xFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xTargetFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xFlag As Boolean

On Error Resume Next

If Item.Class = olMail Then
    Set xMailItem = Item
    xFlag = False
    If xMailItem.Categories <> "" Then
        Set xFlds = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
        If xFlds.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each xFld In xFlds
                If xFld.Name = xMailItem.Categories Then
                    xFlag = True
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If xFlag = False Then
            Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders.Add xMailItem.Categories, olFolderInbox
        End If
        Set xTargetFld = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(xMailItem.Categories)
        xMailItem.Move xTargetFld
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I tried changing certain values to make it check all folders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run code when new email comes to any subfolder in a Shared Mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881358/run-code-when-new-email-comes-to-any-subfolder-in-a-shared-mailbox)

Comment: In Application StartUp you set xInboxItems. This only refers to the Items in your xInboxFld. You need to also "register" the items of the Subfolders. To do this I'd recommend to create a class. That has the Private WithEvents xInboxItems As Outlook.Items. Bascially copy all of the code but the StartUp Method into the class. In the Startup create those classes for your "MainFodler" and your subfolders and store them in a collection.

Comment: First of all thanks for the comments, I do understand now why it doesn't check my subfolders. However, I'm really only getting started with coding/vba (I wrote some Java as a kid for my minecraft server) so I have no idea what exactly to change. Do I just copy paste the code Niton refrenced in between - Set xInboxFld and Set xInboxItems at the application_startup? Also I was wondering why it wouldn't be possible to change the  Set xInboxFld = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) to include the subfolders aswell, because in (my) theory this should also do the job.

Comment: Try something. Edit the question to add the attempt if needed.

Comment: You will increase you chance of success if you remove `On Error Resume Next` so you do not hide errors. As well if you do edit the question you can provide an error message if any.

Comment: A simpler option is to create an event for each folder. An `ItemAdd` example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453348/apply-one-of-two-results-to-incoming-email-with-item-add.